# What is the faster function to read files?

Tags: php, file-io

I am using `fopen()` and `fread()` to read files

```
if( file_exists( $file ) ){
    $open = fopen( $file , 'r' );
    return fread( $open , filesize( $file ) );
}
fclose( $file );
```

My files size is about 10 MB

So, I was wondering if there was anything faster.

`file_get_contents` seems to be faster, but in my searches I found it seems like it uses more ram memory... Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `file_get_contents()` if all you want is to load the entire file into memory, since it's shorter and shows clearly what you are doing.

Also, from the PHP manual on [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> `file_get_contents()` is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use file_get_contents. I'd say user experience is main aspect you should think about

Comment: User experience? When is the user ever going to see the code?

Comment: @genesis thank you for your tip and i'd say me experience is the main aspect!